# How to actually send emails dumped to a pickup directory by SmtpClient

Tags: smtp, smtpclient

This is how i have smtp client setup in web.config:

```
   <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp from="&quot;SSA Notifications&quot; &lt;email@example.com&gt;" deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">
            <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="e:\pickup"/>             
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
   </system.net>
```

So when I send email using SmtpClient, it doesn't actually send it but dumps it into the pickup folder - that's by design, mostly for testing purposes. Now, if I want those generated emails to actually get sent, what do I do (I don't care if it will be some code or a power shell script)?

Answer (score 0):

You can run worker thread to pickup eml from that directory and then send from there. Or you can use third party agent to send email from that folder.

Pickup directory is intended for third party email client software.